# How to determine which directory a link is pointing to using bash

Tags: bash, shell, symlink

With Bash scripting, is there a way to determine which directory a link is pointing to, then switch it to another directory based on the result?

For example, say I have the two following directories:

`/var/data/1/` and `/var/data/2/`

I have a link to one of them, say, `data_link` and it is currently linked to `/var/data/1/`

When the script is triggered, I want it to swap the link to `/var/data/2/` (i.e. `ln -s /var/data/2/ /somepath/data_link`).

When the script is triggered again, the opposite will happen (i.e. `ln -s /var/data/1/ /somepath/data_link`), and so on.  What's the easiest way to do this via a Bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `readlink` command to get the content of a link:

```
$TARGET=$(readlink "$LINK")
```

Then use standard `if` to inspect the current value, `rm` to remove it, and `ln` as you indicated to re-create with the new desired target.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the standard set of unix utilities doesn't include an easy access to the `readlink` system call. Some systems include a `readlink` command. If it's available, there's a good chance that `readlink foo` prints the target of the symlink `foo`. If you feel tempted to use options, be warned that there are multiple versions of this command floating around; you won't get portability even between Linux distributions.

If you have perl available, `perl -e 'print readlink $ARGV[0]' mylink` prints the target of `mylink`.

If you need a portable way and don't have Perl or anything else sane, you can perhaps make do with parsing the  output of `ls -l mylink`.

If you have a symbolic link to a directory that you have permission to change into, then `$(cd mylink && command -p pwd)` is the absolute path to the ultimate target of the link. For example, if `foo` is a symlink to `/var/tmp/bar`, `bar` is a directory in `/var/tmp` and `/var/tmp` is a symbolic link to `/tmp`, this command yields `/tmp/bar`.